LTV not enabled in PDFBox after applying AddValidationInformartion
I already signed a document with PDFBox Create Signature file that provided at the example repository by PDFBox. Then I try to apply LTV Enabling the document with AddValidationInformation file provided by PDFBox, but I got an issue that the ltv still not enabled which looks like this.
enter image description here
I just download the full code repo from PDFBox at 18 November 2024, I use IntelliJ Idea and set the SDK to 23.
Any input for this issue?

Can you share the PDF before and after AddValidationInformation for analysis?
